# How to find order of $T$ if $T(n) = 3 \cdot T(n/3) + n \cdot \log_2 \log_2 n$

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, approximation

> How to find order of $T$ if $T(n) = 3 \cdot T(n/3) + n \cdot \log_2
>  \log_2 n$

I know from lecture that recurrence like 
$$T(n) = a \cdot T(n/b) + f(n) $$

can be approximated in use of sum for $n=b^k$:
$$ T(b^k) =  aT(b^{k-1}) + f(b^k) = ... = a^k T(1) + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i f(b^{k-i}) $$
In my case I got
$$T(3^k) = 3^k T(1) + \sum_{i=0}^{k} 3^k \log_2
 \log_2 3^i$$
But what should be done next?

I have problem with calculate that part:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} 3^k \log_2
 \log_2 3^i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} 3^k \log_2
 \log_2 3^i = 3^k \sum_{i=1}^{k} \log_2
 \log_2 3^i $$

Comment: I guess what you want is called *q-difference equations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $u(n):=\frac{T(n)}{n\log_2\log_2n}$ so $$u(n)=u(n/3)\frac{\log_2\log_2(n/3)}{\log_2\log_2n}+1.$$Asymptotically, $\frac{\log_2\log_2(n/3)}{\log_2\log_2n}\sim1$ so $$u(n)\sim\log_3n,\,T(n)\sim n\log_3 n\cdot\log_2\log_2n.$$In big-O notation, we can simplify this to $T(n)\in O(n\ln n\cdot\ln\ln n)$.

Comment: I am considering your solution: this approach is general or just in this exercise it worked?

Comment: @VirtualUser You'll often find it helps to try something like this.

Comment: It seems to be much more smarter than using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

Comment: @VirtualUser Yes, but that's an odd result to bring up for this.

Comment: Do you know how proposed approach can be finished? I mean finishing $\sum_{i=0}^{k} 3^k \log_2
 \log_2 3^i = \sum_{i=1}^{k} 3^k \log_2
 \log_2 3^i = 3^k \sum_{i=1}^{k} \log_2
 \log_2 3^i$

Comment: I tried to put that to wolfram but it returns me edited input: $\sum _{i=0}^k \frac{\log (2)}{\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{\log \left(3^i\right)}\right)}$

Comment: @VirtualUser $\log_2\log_23^i=\log_2(i\log_23)=\log_2i+\log_2\log_23$, so $\sum_{i=1}^k\log_2\log_23^i=\frac{\log 2}{2}k(k+1)+(\log_2\log_23)k$. But I don't recommend that approach to solving the original problem.

Comment: why don't you  recommend that approach?